# Should a suspended hyphen be used for '10-to 15-year-olds'?

Tags: punctuation, hyphens

Should I use suspended hyphen in the example below like *10-to 15-year-olds*?

> The time spend by **10 to 15-year-olds** on two activities.

Comment: If you could provide a link to one or more uses of such punctuation as *10 to 15-year-olds* that would be helpful. Hyphenation usage is always changing.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, the hyphen should follow *10*. In addition, a space should follow this hyphen, indicating that *10-* is attached to *year-...*, not to *to*:

> ...the time spent by 10- to 15-year-olds on two activities

Note that *spent*, the past participle of *spend*, is employed as an attributive.

Comment: yes, I just misspelled it,... the next thing I want to make sure,  should this rule, suspended hypens,  be necessarily followed in academic writing ? because in some samples I have seen such phrases be used with hypens following only 15-  and years- ,  "like "10 to 15-year-olds"

Comment: @CavidHummatov Yes, do follow the "rule"; it is a typographic device which helps the reader parse your meaning.